# How to implement "Don't show it to me anymore" in GWT?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am coding an application, there is a drop down in GUI contains values that are directly from back end data. However, there is a new requirement coming, when user is browsing the drop down and click delete button from keyboard/right click mouse, we should hide the value in drop down and don't show it anymore in GUI, but I don't want to delete the hided value in back end database.

The difficulty for me is how can I store the filtered drop down list values in my GWT java code? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [HTML5 Storage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html)?

Comment: Or the more basic approach, cookies. Obviously, the client side can delete them, so it all depends on whether this is acceptable for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want each client to have data stored on what they've deleted. Instead of having to track each client's decisions in the database, you should have the information stored on the client's machine. This can be done in a preferences file, HTML5 Storage, etc depending on what kind of client it is. If the client changes computers, their data won't be saved, but I don't think that's unexpected behavior. It really depends on the application and what you expect. Either way, store the client and their deletions in a separate table or on their own machine.